# Using DatePicker to get the current day within the year in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, date, datepicker

I am currently programming a new Windows Phone Application and within this app i want the user to be able to find the hex date for any date of their choice. For this reason i am letting the user use a date picker to choose their desired date. Before i included the date picker i was allowing the user to get the hex date for today's date by using the following code:

```
        ReverseString = 365 - DateTime.Today.DayOfYear
        txtReverseJulian.Text = ReverseString.PadLeft(3, "0")
```

However now i can't use the DateTime function because i am letting them choose a date from the date picker, how can i change this code so that it will work?

Thank you

Comment: Is this supposed to shows days until the end of the year?  What about leap years?

Comment: I have an IF function that determines whether it is a leap year, should it be a leap year i instead minus the date from 366

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing at what you are trying to do...  Could you provide clarification?

```
    Dim foo As DateTime = New DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 12, 31) 'last day of the current year
    Dim ldoy As Integer = foo.DayOfYear 'number of days in year
    Dim dr As Integer = ldoy - DateTime.Today.DayOfYear 'number of days until end of year
```

Using a DatePicker

```
    Dim foo As DateTime = New DateTime(aDatePicker.Value.Year, 12, 31) 'last day of the current year
    Dim ldoy As Integer = foo.DayOfYear 'number of days in year
    Dim dr As Integer = ldoy - aDatePicker.Value.DayOfYear 'number of days until end of year
```

Comment: It tells me that year is not a member of 'date'.

Comment: If this is DatePicker try using SelectedDate instead of Value.

Comment: It doesn't give me the option to use SelectedDate im afraid.

Comment: And yes it is a DatePicker

Comment: I changed the code to use the current system date.  DatePicker or Windows forms DateTimePicker?

Comment: The datepicker is from the microsoft.phone.controls.toolkit

Comment: I know how to do the current date its just if i want to change the date using the date picker so i can see previous reverse julian dates :/

Comment: From what I can tell the DatePicker has a Value property that is of type DateTime and DateTime has a Year property, so I don't know why the previous code did not work.

Comment: If i add a full stop after value i getting the following options:
Equals, GetHashCode, GetType, GetValueOrDefault, HasValue, ReferenceEquals, ToString, Value.

if that is of any help

Comment: Sorry.  I don't have WP7 but it did look like the DateTime was the same.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, i have literally just fixed it, the issue was that you couldn't convert it to the day of year, first i had to convert is the the DateTime type and give that value to a variable. Once this had been done i could then type the variable and then a full stop and the DayOfYear option would appear. Thank you for the help anyway :)

Comment: The `Value` property returns a nullable DateTime (`DateTime?`). Check first if it has a value (with `HasValue`) before using the `Value`.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
//Here is event fire when datepicker value will be change
 ValueChanged="DatePicker_ValueChanged"
Private Sub DatePicker_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DateTimeValueChangedEventArgs)
ReverseString = e.NewDateTime.Value.ToString()
End Sub   
txtReverseJulian.Text = ReverseString.PadLeft(3, "0")
```

Comment: Thank you that worked ill mark it as the correct answer when i can :) just one other thing, what event can i place this in so when i change the date picker value the reverse julian date will change?

Comment: @CharlieStuart I made change in my answer please check it and let me know if it works.

Comment: Sorry i've just realised it does not work, when i change the date it still displays as the same, isn't the date picker just being converted to today's date?

Comment: Please remember i am programming in VB.NET not C#

Comment: @CharlieStuart are you using  "protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)" event in your code file ?

Comment: @CharlieStuart Ok I made some more changes in  my code. Please give a look.

Comment: You have still wirtten the code in C#, i am writing in VB.NET

Comment: @CharlieStuart I made change c# to vb Now check it